# Performance issues access large Excel file

Tags: excel, microsoft-graph-api

We have a large Excel file (~10k rows) with just a few columns hosted on SharePoint Online.  One of the columns is an email address and we want to filter this column based on the current user.

A JavaScript webpage using Microsoft Graph reads all rows.  It's very slow (> 20 seconds sometimes) because we read the entire file in and filter using client code (usually less than 50 rows of the 10k rows)

The Microsoft Graph call looks like this:

```
/v1.0/sites/{site}/drives/{id{/items/{id}/workbook/tables/2/rows
```

Any suggestions that might help with performance,  like indexing the Excel and filtering server side somehow with Views, A filter, URL parameters or something else like lookup tables,  powerquery or powerpivot?

Comment: Without seeing the code you're using, this question is just too broad to answer. There are just too many variables that could affect the performance.

Comment: You might want to download first the file and do the parsing locally.

Answer (score 1):

You can use table column's [Filter API](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/filter_apply) to filter the values.

```
POST /workbook/tables/{id|name}/columns/{id|name}/filter/apply
    {
        filterOn: "Values",
        values: ["email@mail.com", "email2@mail.com"]
    }
```

Then you can read the visible range using [this API](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/workbookrangeview_list_rows).

You can clear the filter at the end.

If not, you can just read the column values you are interested in from the unfiltered table. That will reduce the payload and help improve the perf.